# How do I filter a views page with contextual filters?

Tags: views

I have an all events views page where I would like to put the links 'All Events', 'Upcoming Events', 'Past Events' in the header.

I would like to link them to the same views page but show filtered results. It seems possible by looking at contextual filters but not sure which way to go.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

you can add exposed filters to show past and future events. When you use the filters you'll see the URLs it generates. Those are your links and you can add them to the header of the view with a "global text area".
You can now hide the exposed filter forms by setting "Exposed form in block:" to yes. That will remove them from the view.

Comment: Thanks for replying.When the exposed filter field setting was set to relative date 'now' it loaded with today's date, however when the apply button was clicked, the url showed that the date was embedded as static. I would require this to still be 'now'. Is that possible?

Comment: for dates in the future you can set "event date" "is great than" "+0 days". The "+0 days" is basically "now". I'm using D7, are you on D6?

Comment: I am using D7 and so far this is the url I have:

`http://<mydomainname>/myevents/events?field_event_start_date_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=2010&field_event_start_date_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D=10&field_event_start_date_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bday%5D=19`

I need to somehow replace the '2010' in the url to be 'now' so everytime the url is accessed the filter dynamically filters according to today's date.

I did manage to show the drop-down filter and show events depending on the chosen date, but using the resultant url as a link would not work then as the date is static.